# Second fundamental theorem of calculus for function of two variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Hi I'm trying to understand **Second fundamental theorem of calculus** when it is used for function of two variables $ f(x,y) $.

As we know from Second Fundamental Theorem, when we have a continuous function $f(x)$ and fix constant a, then

From $$ F(x) =  \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt $$ it follows that $ F'(x) = f(x) $

It's shown on the picture below:

[image]

I'm reading now a proof of theorem where is continuous function of two variables $f(x,y)$ with equation:

$$ \frac{ \partial f(x,y)}{ \mbox{d} x } = P(x,y) $$

It is written in book that from **Second Fundamental Theorem** it follows that:

$$ f(x,y) =  \int_{x_0}^{x} P(x,y) dx + R(y) $$

where $x_0$ i constant and $R(y)$ stands for the arbitrary constant of integration.

I don't why we have here constant $R(y)$. How can this be explained? The propoal here follows from derivative to integral but in theorem it follows from integral to derivative. So is it correct proposal?

I would be greateful for explanation of my doubts. Best regards ;)

Comment: $R$ is a function that doesn’t depend on $x$, so ${\partial R\over\partial x}=0$. This is completely analogous to the single-variable case, where adding a constant $c$ to the antiderivative also gives an antiderivative because $c'=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea in the R(y) term is that the book is basically thinking that for each fixed y, there is a function $g_y(x) = f(x,y)$, so that the partial derivative of $f$ is the (ordinary) derivative of $g_y.$ Then the fundamental theorem can be applied to $g$ giving
$$ g_y(x) = \int_{x_0}^x g_y'(x) dx + c.$$
This is true for any fixed $y$, although the $c$ may be different for each $y$--i.e. $c$ is a function of $y$. Changing notation from $g$ to $f$ gives the formula from your book, where $R(y)$ gives the $c$ associated to each $y$.

Also, I think you are just mixing up the first and second theorem.

Comment: Ok  thanks for answering. Don't you know where could I find something similar about that? Maybe any links, books where could I find any concrete examples, with concrete functions with that usage this theorem? Sometimes when I calc some examples, then I can understand idea well ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a reference, as it's been too many years since I learned it. It's also the sort of thing that is often not formally explained very well in textbooks. The best advice I can give is to look through some multi variable calculus textbooks and you will probably get lucky within about three attempts. I did find this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation. In the intro section it briefly explains a related concept. The partial differential equations people do this all the time but that may be too advanced material.